# Way to keep track of people and organizations?

Tags: trello-organization, crm

I am looking for a flexible web app that would allow me to keep track of all the local "chapters" of an organization (world wide). A multi-chapter website management software.

Ideally it would function like a CRM (e.g. [Highrise](http://highrisehq.com/), [Capsule](http://capsulecrm.com/)) but allow each "chapter" to update its own contact information online.

We would need the ability to create custom fields and control who has access to view / edit those fields.

Comment: You may want to speak to HighRise team and see if they can work out a special case for you. With the criteria you have imposed on this question it is too localized.

Comment: I disagree that the question is too localized, I believe there are likely to be web-based apps for this in the marketplace.  Google for "web-based membership management software" - then filter out the ones that are not web-based.  Please comment if you have any luck.

Comment: @phwd Please reopen this question, I believe it is proper for webapps - there is a whole marketplace for these products - please google (see above) to see for yourself.

Comment: It seems [Wild Apricot](http://www.wildapricot.com/multi-chapter-website-pricing) is able to do this. I am not familiar with this topic but it seems that it is not localized as I originally thought based on those searches you gave @arrocharJames

Comment: Are you looking for on-premise software, a hosted solutoin, or a SaaS solution?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [**iFreeTools Creator** - an online database application builder](http://creator.ifreetools.com), which I am building over Google App Engine.

iFreeTools Creator allows defining your own custom database by specifying the Entities (or "tables") and Attributes (or "fields" / "columns") and get started with using your online database in minutes.

Help Docs : http://help.creator.ifreetools.com

For your specific usecase, you will find the Authorization Profiles feature useful. Auth Profiles enables fine-grain access control up to field level. The following blog post gives an overview of the feature..
http://blogs.ifreetools.com/2010/12/access-control-up-to-field-level-now.html

You may also find useful the Google Maps based geo-location feature, wherein attributes of *Geo Point* data-type can be defined to mark geographic locations and can further be used to search based on nearness to a given location (*show me all chapters near xyz*).

If you require assistance in using the app, you can use the feedback form in the app to get in touch with me.

Comment: This is not what the user asked for. He wants a flexible app ready made to manage multiple chapters in a presentable website format.

Answer (score -1):

Since there was no requirement that it had to be free - Would [SalesForce.com](http://www.salesforce.com) fit the bill here?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has an offering for this type of thing called [Sharepoint](http://www.sharepoint.com). It provides the features you mention as well as many more beyond those.